# SQL Query with fields of type NUMERIC

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this one

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    [MyTableID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AddressType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
        [MyTableID] ASC
    )
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Can somebody explain why the following query works even if I am including the field value within single quotes?

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyTableID = '1'
```

Is this a SQL Server specific feature? It is ANSI/SQL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you've demonstrated is commonly referred to as implicit data conversion - the data is automatically converted to the data type of the column being compared to.  Because a string with a value of "1" can be converted to a numeric data type with a value of 1, things work just fine.  Implicit data type conversions can occur according to the [precedence list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) here.

Explicit data conversion is when you use functions like [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

String to numeric (and vice versa) is supported on all the databases I know of - SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL...  The CAST function is ANSI, IIRC.  Other data types aren't as flexible - dates & datetimes for instance.

Comment: This kind of implicit data conversion is specific to SQL Server right? I am almost sure that the query will fail against Oracle and DB2

Comment: @Lorenzo: I've updated while you were commenting, but no - it's not specific to SQL Server.

Comment: Ok! Thank you very much for the explanation. I have just discovered this while I was trying to cause an error in my code. If I knew this before, some of the query builder classes I wrote were much simpler :)

Comment: @Lorenzo - But be aware of performance considerations before jumping in and doing this!

Comment: @Martin: There's always a drawback when things seems simpler! :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to OMG Ponies answer.

Implicit data type conversions can occur according to the [precedence list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) here.

They can be a source of performance problems when the datatype of a constant or parameter in a predicate has a higher precedence than that of the column. In this case the column values will need to undergo an implicit conversion meaning an index cannot be used.

Comment: I added the precedence list to my answer; I keep forgetting about it.